# Daylight Savings and Cron

Tags: cron, dst

If Cron has a job scheduled to run at 2 am and one at 3 am how would those jobs be affected by daylight savings time?

When the time shifts back an hour does the time go from 2:59:59 am to 2:00:00 am directly? Meaning that the 2 am job would run twice and the 3 am job would run once? Or is does the time first change to 3:00:00 am and then 2:00:00 am causing both jobs to run twice?

When the time shifts forward an hour does the time go from 1:59:59 am to 3:00:00 am causing the 2 am job to not run and the 3 am job to run once? Or does the time shift from 2:00:00 to 3:00:00 am causing both jobs to run once?

In short what I am wondering is when gaining an hour does the 3 am hour happen once or twice and and losing an hour does the 2 am hour happen at all. I have not been able to find anything about this when looking on Google.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

The answer would be dependent on the variant/extension of cron you are using. Some variants do not handle the Daylight Saving Time, leading to missing jobs and twice run of the job.

If you are using the Paul Vixie cron, then it does handle the DST changes. As per the [cron man page](https://web.archive.org/web/20130905110602/http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?cron+8):

> cron checks each minute to see if its spool directory's
> modtime (or the modtime on /etc/crontab) has changed

And further, with reference to Daylight Saving Time (The 2nd paragraph clearly explains your answer)

> Daylight Saving Time and other time changes
>
> Local time changes of less than three hours, such as  those  caused  by
> the  start or end of Daylight Saving Time, are handled specially.  This
> only applies to jobs that run at a specific time and jobs that are  run
> with  a  granularity  greater  than  one hour.  Jobs that run more fre-
> quently are scheduled normally.
>
> If time has moved forward, those jobs that would have run in the inter-
> val that has been skipped will be run immediately.  Conversely, if time
> has moved backward, care is taken to avoid running jobs twice.
>
> Time changes of more than 3 hours are considered to be  corrections  to
> the clock or timezone, and the new time is used immediately.

So, whenever the time shifts may be 2:59:59 or at 3:00:00, cron's taking care of the job runs by handling the situation and running only the missed ones and avoids running the already ran jobs.

Comment: The link is broken. What Paul Vixie cron. I have found nothing on internet.

Comment: Here is a link to an archive of the non-existent page: https://web.archive.org/web/20130905110602/http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?cron+8 and here is a current site that hosts linux man pages: https://linux.die.net/man/8/cron

Answer (score 2):

To make it clear, it depends on where you live, how your cron jobs are scheduled (Unix cron which you need to take care of, while Java scheduler which take care by itself!).

In the U.S., clocks change at 2:00 a.m. local time. In spring, clocks spring forward from 1:59 a.m. to 3:00 a.m.; in fall, clocks fall back from 1:59 a.m. to 1:00 a.m.

In the EU, clocks change at 1:00 a.m. Universal Time. In spring, clocks spring forward from 12:59 a.m. to 2:00 a.m.; in fall, clocks fall back from 1:59 a.m. to 1:00 a.m.

Example: if you have a Unix cron job at 1:30 am on today 25 October  2020, your jobs run twice.

Comment: It should be clear from my question which time change I am talking about as I specify the hours before and after the change. This is also different than the accepted answer as well.

Answer (score -4):

2023 update for those that find this Q:

**Servers should never run on Daylight Savings time**

Too many things break when daylight savings ends and timestamps repeat themselves. And the admin never remembers that as the root cause of the problems.

But of course not everyone follows best practice.

Modern OS's are great at protecting you from DST spaghetti.

**Desktops may run on Daylight Savings Time**

In which case mtk's answer is still great. Assuming 02:00 changeover time

- Start and End of DST 3am job runs once
- Start of DST 2am job **should** only run once as cron will recognise the clock went from 1:59:59.9999 to 3:00:00.0000 and run the catch up.
- End of DST 2am job will run once

Also good practice is to not schedule user jobs at the top of the hour e.g. start at 02:01am

**Best Practice**

cron can't do 1st Sunday in October etc so your script should manage the DST adjustment.

Comment: Sorry, but there are things that need to run at a set time and adjust for daylight savings time.

Comment: That's what my answer says. You want something to run at 02:00 UTC  year-round? AND your server is UTC (e.g. log rotation) great! You want to run your server on DST local time? It's going to hurt, a lot. You want a report generated at 08:01 local time year round on a UTC server? Run the cron job twice and adjust your shell script to not run at 0900 or 0700. And! don't run Cron shell scripts between 0200 and 0300. Good new is cron is DST aware.

Comment: If I am asking about daylight savings time it is clear that I don't want something to run at 02:00 UTC year round. I want it to run at 02:00 local time and wanted to understand how the shift in time would impact the run.

Comment: "Servers should never run on Daylight time"  -- Did you mean *Servers should never run on **Daylight Saving** time* ?   I think you did of course, right?  But I am reluctant to edit your response because I am not 100% sure.

Comment: Thanks @gregspears I fell into an Aus/EU trap where it is referred to as Standard Time vs Daylight Time. Edited for clarity.

Comment: @paulzag -- oh!  interesting, thx.  I learned something there