# How to extract the UTC offset of a specific date and time using bash?

Tags: linux, bash, timezone, timezone-offset

To be specific I do not want    `date +%z` or    `date -R` for the current local time, but I need something very similar that should work for any date in the past. For example, something like:

`command 2018-04-01 12:33:45`

should return the UTC offset (assume Chicago as my local time zone) at 12:33:45 on 1st April 2018 local time, Chicago time for example.

I searched extensively and there, probably, is no question close to this one, everyone wants current offset not date-time specific one, therefore it is not a duplicate.

Thanks very much

Update:

I have found something [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16027776/getting-a-previous-date-in-bash-unix), that asnwers how to get past dates using `date` command, then I have combined it with `-R` to get something close to what I want:

`date -d "35 days ago" -R`

I can go 35 days back and get the UTC offset.

Comment: what about `date -d 2018-04-01T12:33:45 -R`

Comment: Consider providing an answer to your question if the given answer is not sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

To convert a particular date time to UTC you can use below command

for example date you provided in your question

`2018-04-01 12:33:45`

It would be something like below

```
date -u --date=@$(date "+%s" --date="2018-04-01 12:33:45")
```

which would have output similar to `Sun Apr  1 10:33:45 UTC 2018`

If you would like to achieve `command date` here then you can either create a command alias for above command or use above command in your script providing the date value to convert as an `argument`

Answer (score 0):

I am answering my own question based on

1. My own update just after submitting the question.
2. [Nahuel Fouilleul](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1454708/nahuel-fouilleul)'s comment.

Quoting from my own "edit":

"I have found something [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16027776/getting-a-previous-date-in-bash-unix), that answers how to get past dates using date command, then I have combined it with `-R` to get something close to what I want:

`date -d "35 days ago" -R`

I can go 35 days back and get the UTC offset."

here comes [Nahuel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1454708/nahuel-fouilleul)'s comment, "what about `date -d 2018-04-01T12:33:45 -R`"

That is in line with what I wrote in my "edit". Nahuel's solution works perfectly for me.

also [Usman Malik](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49983657/4962474)'s answer perfectly provides the solution.

So to summarize, my (not entirely though) answer will be:

`date -d specific_past_date -R`

where the specific_past_date is the date on which I need the UTC offset, using the date and time that I mentioned in my question, if I do:

`date -d 2018-04-01T12:33:45 -R`

I get `Sun, 01 Apr 2018 12:33:45 -0500` from Chicago, that means Chicago time was **5** hours behind UTC on 1st April 2018 at 12:33:45.