# Print the path of a file a day before and a day after in Shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix-timestamp

I am having a shell script like below

```
#!/bin/bash

TIMESTAMP=`date "+%Y-%m-%d"`
path=/home/$USER/logging/${TIMESTAMP}/status/${TIMESTAMP}.fail_log

echo filePath=$path
```

In this script I want to print the `path` of the failed logs for that particular timestamp.

Now I am able to get the `echo` to print the path.

How do I print a day before and day after the `timestamp`? Is it possible to do that?

How Can I do that in a single line of code? Can we do that?

Comment: Have you actually searched, using the related [SO questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15374752/get-yesterdays-date-in-bash-on-linux-dst-safe)?

Comment: `date  --date="yesterday"`, `date  --date="tomorrow"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get tomorrow's data, you can do:

```
date -d '+1 day' "+%Y-%m-%d"
```

To get yesterday's data, you can do:

```
date -d '-1 day' "+%Y-%m-%d"
```

To use it in script:

```
#!/bin/bash

nextDate=$(date -d '+1 day' "+%Y-%m-%d")
prevDate=$(date -d '-1 day' "+%Y-%m-%d")

nextDatePath=/home/$USER/logging/${TIMESTAMP}/status/${nextDate}.fail_log

prevDatePath=/home/$USER/logging/${TIMESTAMP}/status/${prevDate}.fail_log
```