# Yesterdays and Next date from given date using ksh on AIX

Tags: unix, ksh, aix

I'm trying to write a script in that need to compute date-1 and date+1 after

reading the Date from variable

echo `2017-09-30` | read YYYY MM DD

how to print next date as 2017-10-01  trying on AIX OS  .

This is  the piece of code from it

```
date ()
{
   DAY=$D1
   TODAY=$D1
   DAY1=$D1
   echo $DAY1| read YYYY MM DD
   let DD=DD+1
   DD=`printf %02d $DD`
   if [[ $DD -eq 0 ]] then
   let MM=MM-1
   MM=`printf %02d $MM`
   if [[ $MM -eq 0 ]] then
   let YYYY=YYYY-1
   let MM=12
   let DD=31
   fi
   DD=`cal $MM $YYYY|grep . |fmt -1|tail -1`
  fi
  NEXTDAY=`echo $YYYY-$MM-$DD`
  echo $NEXTDAY
  }
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to ask a proper question and improve yours according the guidelines.

Comment: Does your ksh support date/time printing such as `printf "%(%s)T\n" 2017-09-30` ?

Comment: Does your `awk`  support `mktime` ?

Comment: @WalterA  it's not supported

Answer (score 0):

Tomorrow:

```
date --date='tomorrow'
date --date='1 day'
```

Yesterday:

```
date --date='yesterday'
date --date='1 day ago'
```

How to save time/date format to the shell variable?

```
$ NOW=$(date +"%m-%d-%Y")
```

To display a variable use echo command:

```
$ echo $NOW
```

Comment: Thanks Zappe , its not from system's date , its from variable

Answer (score 0):

I answered yesterday at https://stackoverflow.com/a/21283578/3220113

You can have yesterday and tomorrow with the same method, keeping in mind the Daylight Saving Time:

```
# Tomorrow
echo "$(TZ=GMT-30 date +%Y-%m-%d)
$(TZ=GMT-20 date +%Y-%m-%d)" | grep -v $(date +%Y-%m-%d) | head -1

# Yesterday
echo "$(TZ=GMT+30 date +%Y-%m-%d)
$(TZ=GMT+20 date +%Y-%m-%d)" | grep -v $(date +%Y-%m-%d) | tail -1
```

Comment: Its not for tomorrow and yesterday from system's date , its from variable - date varies .

Comment: When you can't install GNU dae or GNU awk, you will need to look for some huge script. I started looking for you, but you have to judge the links which might be suited for you after some changes:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3125174/3220113 or https://decipherinfosys.wordpress.com/2009/07/28/getting-previous-date-in-korn-shell-on-aix-ksh/ or https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.unix.shell/s_MJvMbvLDs