# Yesterday's date variable in BASH on AIX Server

Tags: bash, unix-timestamp, aix

I want to store yesterday's date in BASH variable to search for yesterday's files with that variable in the file-name wildcard search. I am using the following format for New York City, NY, USA (EST) time zone, and wanted to know whether it is guaranteed to fetch yesterday's date from the system date; else I can make further changes to the variable.

```
 yesterday=$(TZ=GMT+28 date +%Y%m%d)
 ...
  for file in $HOME_DIR/*$yesterday*.txt;
 ...
```

The text filename in HOME_DIR would be as follows:
"ABC_20171011064612.txt"

update 1: Attempt for removing daylight savings related issues:

`yesterday=$(echo -e "$(TZ=GMT+28 date +%Y%m%d)\n$(TZ=GMT+18 date +%Y%m%d)"|grep -v $(date +%Y%m%d)|sort|tail -1)`

1) Convert two dates to string, 24 hours and 14 (picked arbitrarily to be less than 24 hours) hours before today's date

2) Filter for dates that are not today's date

3) Sort strings from 2) in ascending order

4) Assign `yesterday` variable to last `tail -1` entry of the list

Comment: Maybe try **Perl**... `perl -MPOSIX -le '@now = localtime; $now[3]--; print scalar localtime mktime @now'`

Comment: Which version of bash? If you have 4.3, then you can use `printf %()T` to do date formatting using shell-builtin operations, so you can extract epoch time and then subtract.

Comment: `GNU bash, version 4.3.30(1)-release (powerpc-ibm-aix5.1.0.0)`

Comment: How about https://stackoverflow.com/a/21283578/3220113 ?

Comment: Greetings Walter A, Thank you, I will try out the AIX grep solution mentioned on that link to circumvent daylight savings issues.

Comment: Using the above link, I was able to induce the following solution-attempt:

`yesterday=$(echo -e "$(TZ=GMT+28 date +%Y%m%d)\n$(TZ=GMT+18 date +%Y%m%d)|grep -v $(date +%Y%m%d)|sort|tail -1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You attempted

```
yesterday=$(echo -e "$(TZ=GMT+28 date +%Y%m%d)\n$(TZ=GMT+18 date +%Y%m%d)|
            grep -v $(date +%Y%m%d)|sort|tail -1)
```

I think it worked.

Answer (score 1):

It may not be always right due to DST, although it will not be a big issue.
You could rather say:

```
yesterday=$(date -d yesterday +%Y%m%d)
```

Comment: I get 
`date: not recognized flag d `

Comment: Sorry...  I've just learned AIX date(1) does not accept -d option.
Your first approach $(TZ=GMT+28 date +%Y%m%d) should properly work anyway except  for around midnight.
Modifying TZ is a commonly used workaround to calculate shifted time and day.